# UITableView imageView Shows Image Where An Image Should Not Be After Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a uitableview with a list of people in it.  some records have an image and some records do not.  If i scroll down through the list it appears correct but if i scroll back up then an image of another person starts to show on other people's cell row where an image should not be.  Here is my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
// START CELL LABELLING FOR  TABLE VIEW LIST //
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    Person *person = [arrayOfPersons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    NSString *personPhoto = person.personPhoto;

    NSString* imgPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", personPhoto] ];



    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imgPath]){
        NSLog(@"FILE EXISTS");

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 0, 67, 67)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Does Not Exist");
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = person.personName;



    return cell;
    imageView = nil;
    personPhoto = @"";
    imgPath = @"";
}
// END CELL LABELLING FOR TABLE VIEW LIST //
```

Comment: probably you need to do [cell.contentView.view removeFromSuperview]; somewhere before add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because table cells get re-used.

When you use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]`, you get back a cell that has already been shown in your table view (for a different index path). You may have already added an image view to this cell for the Person at this previous index path, and nowhere do you remove this image.

Therefore, when the current Person doesn't have a photo, the previous image will remain visible in the cell.

I would recommend creating your own `UITableViewCell` subclass and adding a `UIImageView` to it, so that you can easily get a reference back to the image view (or you could use a view tag, if you prefer).

Either way, you need to remove the image view/set the image to `nil` when the person does not have a photo.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction for creating my own UITableViewCell

Comment: You would create a `UITableViewCell` subclass (`File > New > File`). You can then setup the layout as needed (either in code or with interface builder). You would add a public outlet for the photo's image view, which you can then set the image for in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method (as well as other stuff (labels etc) that you might need). I hope this makes sense :)